# Can I use current versions of the Ionic CLI and Cordova for an ionic-1 project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I have to make edits to a project built with Ionic-1. I haven't used Ionic before. My only instructions to get the project running are to run `ionic cordova platform add ios`, `ionic cordova platform build android`, `ionic cordova build ios`, and `ionic cordova build android`.

**What I Want To Know:** In the `ionic.config.json` file it indicates that the project uses `ionic1`. I've installed the current `@ionic/cli` and `cordova` with npm. Is there anything else immediate I should know? For example, will I automatically have to use an older version of ionic or cordova in order to work with an ionic-1 project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will have to use the older version.
If the project isn't big yet I suggest you to update it to the newest version or at least to Ionic 3 and then to some minor changes for everything to work again properly.
If you can, copy the package.json in here as well so we can help you better.

here you can find the official migration Guide: https://ionicframework.com/docs/reference/migration

Comment: The project is big enough that I won't be able to change from Ionic-1. Any other advice offhand as I get into it? Anything I should be aware of right off the bat?